# Flutter: How do I put a http get function in MobX instead of using initState from StateFul Widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, mobx, flutter-provider

I am coding a Pokedex app with API, with simple http get, my StateFul Widget looks like this:

```
class _PokemonGridState extends State<PokemonGrid> {
  List? pokedex;

  Future<void> searchPokemonGOData() async {
    var url = Uri.http(
      'raw.githubusercontent.com',
      '/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/master/pokedex.json',
    );
    await http.get(url).then(
      (value) {
        if (value.statusCode == 200) {
          var decodeJsonData = jsonDecode(value.body);
          pokedex = decodeJsonData['pokemon'];
          setState(() {});
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     if (mounted) {
       searchPokemonGOData();
     }
  }
```

I want to use the function `searchPokemonGOData()` from MobX controller but I don't know how, the store file and .g file are already ready. I want something to replace the `initState()` from StateFul, is that possible?